# border for EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I saw many related discussions but didn't find a suitable solution. What I need to do is to create a black border on the top and the bottom sides of an EditText widget. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with a NinePatchDrawable background.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Just create your custom `EditText` or set a suitable drawable as a background.